# How to use rateable in silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I am newbie in silver stripe.

I have added the extension
https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-rateable

But, I am unable to understand how to use this extension....

I am unable to create the data object... please help....

"Then in your templates you can use $RateableUI, when in the context of your rateable object to render the star rating UI"

this step i am unable to understand

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never used this extension but the way I see it you could do for example:

Add the extension to the `DataObjects` you want in `_config.php`:

```
Object::add_extension('ApplePage', 'Rateable');
Object::add_extension('Apple', 'Rateable');
```

Remember to run `dev/build`.

Here `ApplePage` is a Page with a `$has_many` relations `'Apples' => 'Apple'`

Then in you `ApplePage.ss` template you could use something like:

```
<p>Rate my Apple Page: $RateableUI</p>
<p>Apple list</p>
<ul>
   <% loop %>
     <li>$Name (Rating: $RateableUI)</li>
   <% end_loop %>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is what I explained above using the extension you linked. All you have to do is apply the example to your own DataObject/Page. Without more info about your code, that's all we can do. I don't see why the down vote.